# MySQL --- Explicit INNER JOIN with selection from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Whenever I have a need to do an inner join where I have to select columns from multiple tables, I have got the syntax working correctly with implicit joins, without any difficulty.  However, I have struggled to get it working with explicit inner joins.

Let me illustrate with an example from the [MySQL World Database](http://dimitrik.free.fr/mysqltechday_2013_10/world.sql)

My illustrative query, using **implicit inner join**, is as follows:

```
SELECT Name, Language, Percentage
FROM Country, CountryLanguage WHERE Code = CountryCode ;
```

This works as expected.  I can have the columns in any order, from either table, without any issues.

I would like to have the explicit INNER JOIN version of the above query (using "INNER JOIN" and "ON").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace the `,` in your implicit join with the word `JOIN`:

```
SELECT Name, Language, Percentage
FROM Country
JOIN CountryLanguage 
WHERE Code = CountryCode
```

and the query will work fine. You can also replace `WHERE` with `ON` and again it will work fine. Finally if you want to explicitly name the tables where the columns come from (and this is the preferred approach), you would use:

```
SELECT c.Name, cl.Language, cl.Percentage
FROM Country c
JOIN CountryLanguage cl
ON c.Code = cl.CountryCode
```

Comment: I would stick with the second approach

Comment: @Strawberry agreed. I've noted that in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be like

```
SELECT Name, Language, Percentage, 
FROM Country
INNER JOIN CountryLanguage ON Country.Code = CountryLanguage.CountryCode
```

Comment: Sorry im not edit the selects, but in that select in theory, it can select the country values with the countryLanguajes values when two are the same.

Comment: Actually your solution did work once I removed the additional comma after "Percentage" (i.e. "Percentage," to be replaced by "Percentage"). Once you make the change, I will accept your answer.